# Meaning of the word 'apprehension' in following context

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Sentence: *As she had never been in such a situation before, her **apprehension** was understandable.*

Options:

1. eagerness
2. fear
3. hesitation
4. excitement

Comment: Reaching the correct answer here isn't a matter of figuring out which of the possible meanings of _apprehension_ is applicable; it's a matter of looking up _apprehension_ in a dictionary and seeing that only one of the four options is reflected in the dictionary's definitions of the word. Consequently, this is a general-reference question.

Comment: See our [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/346/300). Specifically, "make a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* approach to answering the question".

Answer (score 1):

The first part implies that she is kind of nervous about it since she's never experienced anything like this before. Therefore, I'd cross out **eagerness** and **excitement**.

Based on the definition of *apprehension* on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apprehension):

> anticipation of adversity or misfortune; suspicion or fear of future trouble or evil

I'd choose **fear**. She's likely to be afraid of doing something for the first time. But in a certain context, **hesitation** could be also correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your example sentence, answers **2** and **3** are most likely, but **1** is also possible. It could be a mixture of these, based on further context.

How would the context make a difference? Mainly, it depends on the type of situation she's in.

- Her friend is taking her to the bridal shop to get fitted for her dress. This is the first time she's been a bridesmaid. As she had never been in such a situation before, her **eagerness** was understandable.
- She went for a drive in the country, but now it's dark and she's not sure where she is. As she had never been in such a situation before, her **fear** was understandable.
- She was getting pressured to decide which project needed to be prioritized and which needed to be delayed. As she had never been in such a situation before, her **hesitation** was understandable.